# 'Drag and Drop' Event method on p:dataTable not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I downloaded the PrimeFaces showcase-6.2.war and deployed it on JBoss WildFly 12.0.0.Final running on EE 8. The drag and drop 'DataTable' example works fine.

For a test/PoC I have replicated the showcase example (exactly) just using some of my own data. Which populates & displays in the DataTable.

However, when I drag an item to the 'Selected Pane' I get the error:

> SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default
>   task-1) javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class
>   com.notifywell.controller.NOTiFYwellController.onIngredientDrop(org.primefaces.event.DragDropEvent)

The XHTML that calls this is:

```
<p:droppable for="fieldsetSelectedIngredients" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="dataTableAvailableIngredients" onDrop="handleDrop">
    <p:ajax listener="#{nOTiFYwellController.onIngredientDrop}" update="dropArea dataTableAvailableIngredients" />
</p:droppable>
```

**PrimeFace ShowCase :**

```
<p:ajax listener="#{dndCarsView.onCarDrop}" update="dropArea availableCars" />
```

My Java 'backing bean' with the method ''onIngredientDrop":

```
@Model
@Path("/")
@ViewScoped // OmniFaces 3.1
@Named("nOTiFYwellController")
//@ManagedBean(name="nOTiFYwellController") // Deprecated
public class NOTiFYwellController implements Serializable {
     .....

    public void onIngredientDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Ingredient ingredient = ((Ingredient) ddEvent.getData());

        logger.info("***** onIngredientDrop ddEvent = {}", ddEvent.getData());
    }
}
```

**PrimeFace ShowCase:**

```
public void onCarDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Car car = ((Car) ddEvent.getData());

        droppedCars.add(car);
        cars.remove(car);
}
```

The error is due to the `p:ajax listener` not passing the DragDropEvent parameter.

In the PF ShowCase example, the parameter isn't required. How can I get the 'DragDropEvent' in my backing bean?

If I make the 'onIngredientDrop' method with no parameters it gets called and displays a (revised) log message.

My environment:

> PrimeFace 6.2.3 JSF 2.3 JBoss WildFly 12.0.0.FINAL Java version
>   1.8.0_66 (build 1.8.0_66-b17) Google Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

TIA

Comment: Have you tried annotating your controller with @ViewScoped?

Comment: Yes thanks. I did original miss that off my Bean and added the standard JSF 2.3 one. Which caused "WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type". I Switched to the OmniFaces 3.1 implementation. WELD error has gone, but still, no event parameter passed! Updated code here to show @ViewScoped.

Comment: You code contains a contradiction:  `@Model = @Named +@RequestScoped` And the additional `@Named` is taking the default class name. So please make up your mind.... And an `@Path` on a bean that is used from JSF is also uncommon. Maybe you need to put more code in a service class and call that class from either a `@Path`+`@Mode`l annotated class and Also from a `@Named` and `@ViewScoped`. At the same time that would be weird that you want the usage from two different scoped beans

Comment: And did you check if the import of the DragDropEvent is from the right package (if there are more)

Answer (score 1):

> Your code contains a contradiction: @Model = @Named +@RequestScoped and
>   the additional @Named is taking the default class name. So please make
>   up your mind.... And an @Path on a bean that is used from JSF is also
>   uncommon. Maybe you need to put more code in a service class and call
>   that class from either a @Path+@Model annotated class and Also from a
>   @Named and @ViewScoped. At the same time that would be weird that you
>   want the usage from two different scoped beans – Kukeltje

**Solved by @Kukeltje suggestion**.

Yes, the error was mixing the annotations for a JSF backing bean in my @Model Controller.

I moved the method 'onIngredientDrop' to a 'dedicated' JSF backing bean and included in my WAR for deployment.

```
// @ManagedBean(name = "ingredientBean") // Deprecated
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class IngredientBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     *
     */
    private List<Ingredient> droppedIngredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

    /**
     * @param ddEvent DragDropEvent
     */
    public void onIngredientDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Ingredient ingredient = ((Ingredient) ddEvent.getData());

        logger.info("***** onIngredientDrop ingredient = {}", ingredient.toString());

        //droppedIngredients.add(Ingredient);
    }
}
```

WildFly console output:

> 12:10:04,021 INFO  [com.notifywell.jsf.IngredientBean] (default
>   task-3) ***** onIngredientDrop ingredient =
>   Ingredient{id='5aec3dc5c0a118606e42a11b', ingredientName='Folic Acid'}

Comment: Thanks... I helped and you did not give me the oportunity to create an answer from my comment.  But _**WHY**_ do you use the deprecated `@ManagedBean` annotation in your answer instead of `@Named`?

Comment: I don't. You'll see in the original posting I had: @Named("nOTiFYwellController")
//@ManagedBean(name="nOTiFYwellController") // Deprecated

Comment: That was part of the elimination process. Making it exactly as the PrimeFaces Showcase for 6.2.3. I cut & pasted before I had changed it back to @Named. Answer corrected. You should have more conviction in your answers and posted it. Is it all about reputation & point scoring?

Comment: Sometimes I'm not 100% sure. And no it is not ALL about reputation. If you'd requested to create an answer I'd have said: go ahead, be my guest. Good luck in your future

Comment: I appreciate your help and maybe some of your comments get lost in translation. I'm more than happy to credit your answers. In future, if anyone gives me a suggested answer/solution which solves it,  I will do as suggested and request them to post it as their answer.